# Routing Errorについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

#### 前提・実現したいこと

Routing Errorを解決したい。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

[このサイト](https://cyllabus.jp/courses/LVlXWNb8GcWTKy8x1gHS5g)の『6.つぶやき機能 スタイルを書く』を終了させた時点でlocalhost:3000/tweetsにアクセスしたところ、エラーメッセージが出てしまいました。

```
Routing Error
undefined method `before_filter' for TweetsController:Class Did you mean? before_action

Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/workspace/twitter

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb:2:in `<class:TweetsController>'
app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

#### 該当のソースコード

before_filterとbefore_actionが記述してあるソースコードを載せておきます。

app/controllers/tweets_controller.rb

```rb
class TweetsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :require_login, except: [:index]
    before_action :set_tweet, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    # GET /tweets
```

app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :require_login

    # GET /users
    # GET /users.json
    def index
```

#### 補足情報(言語/FW/ツール等のバージョンなど)

Ruby2.4.1p111
Tera Term
Rails5.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before_filterは以前から非推奨だったので削除されてしまって使えなくなってしまったのだと思います。before_actionに書き換えてください。